# CakePHP Cookies not working after website transfer

Tags: php, cakephp, cookies

I transferred my website from a shared hosting to a VPS and I also changed my domain name. after that I'm constantly getting logged out in 1-2 hour even when I had a code to stay logged in for 1 month.

Here is a snippet of code from `core.php` file

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'cookie' => '_ssi',
    'timeout' => 43200 //30 days
));
```

I searched in Google but I can't find anything related to it. Please guide me in the right direction.

Even the cookies are setting up properly on clients browser.

```
http://i59.tinypic.com/2q8wm1g.png
```

Comment: check your APP/config/bootstrap.php file for something that looks like this 
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.domain.com'); it could be pointing to the wrong domain

Comment: @spectacularbob no there is no such line in my `App/Config/bootstrap.php` file

Comment: It could be that the PHP sessions themselves are cleaned up after 1 or 2 hours. This is set in the global php.ini file of your VPS.